# Documentation on the `find` command in Zsh

Tags: shell, zsh

I have seen the `find` command in many places many times, a couple of examples is:

```
for source in `find $dotfiles_root -maxdepth 2 -name \*.symlink`
```

Or:

```
if ! [ -f git/gitconfig.symlink ]
```

Or:

```
if [ -f $dest ] || [ -d $dest ]
```

Etc. I am aware that if you do `[ -f $dest ]` you're basically doing `find -f $dest`.

So is there any reliable documentation on this command? I haven't been able to find it anywhere if there is.

For example I want it to be able to know how `find $dotfiles_root -maxdepth 2 -name \*.symlink` works, however I can't find out what `-maxdepth` does.

Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: `[ -f $dest ]` is either a shell builtin `[` or external command `[` (I have it in `/usr/bin`). Neither ever calls `find`. More, `find -f $dest` will show you just `find: unknown predicate \`-f'`.

Comment: FYI, `for source in \`find ...\`; do` is a bad way to iterate over the results of the `find` command. Don't write code like that yourself :)

Comment: @ZyX Ah I see. I remember learning they were the same some where, guess that was incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
man find
```

As the options available differ based on the platform you are using, doing a *man* on the command should give you the availble options, and syntax for your particular version.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks. I tried it again and it worked. I did try this in the past but it said it didn't exist. This time I tried with another computer.

Comment: man pages are usually installed, but occasionally they aren't, or can only be access by root. In those cases, you can google 'command_name man page', and it will give you a useful result.